# Laravel 4 Redirect Header

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Right now I'm trying to learn and test Laravel 4, and I have a little concern about script.

I wanted to insert information into the database, then redirect to the index page; the problem is that when I refresh the page, it displays the message to resend.

Here is the code I use:

```
public function store()
{
    $new_cat = new Cat;
    $new_cat->name = Input::get('new_cat');
    $new_cat->age = Input::get('age_cat');

    $new_cat->save();
    return Redirect::action('CatsController@index');

}
```

Comment: Can you post some more code so that there is context for that line?  Also, can you post the error message?

Comment: There are no errors, I redirect to the index page and I refresh it, the browser displays the popup to resend the data.
i just want the browser to not display this popup

Comment: `public function store()
    {
        $new_cat = new Cat;
        $new_cat->name = Input::get('new_cat');
        $new_cat->age = Input::get('age_cat');

        $new_cat->save();
        
        return Redirect::action('CatsController@index');
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe that will work

```
return Redirect::to('route_name')->withInput();
```

Comment: it may be linked with header, as in PHP, you can do:
`header ('Location: index.php');
exit();`

Comment: this is not working in store function, but in route yes... problem with route::resource or what?!!

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to handle a POST request with a redirect is to issue a 303 status code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303

Using your original code:

```
return Redirect::action('CatsController@index', array(), 303);
```

Or Ochi's:

```
return Redirect::to('route_name', 303)->withInput();
```